# Output of fscanf is not coming as expected

Tags: c, scanf

I have written a simple file application to read input data from a file. I have tried to remove space(32) and newline(10). The output is 
File program

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    FILE *f;
    char c;
    unsigned char buf[512],i=0;
    printf("in f_read\n");
    f = fopen("S:\\db\\result-enc.txt","rb");
    while( fscanf( f, "%c", &c ) > 0){
        if(c==32 || c==10)
           ;
        else
           buf[i++]=c;
    }
    buf[i]='\0';
    printf("%s\n",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

data

```
61 AF AF BF 26 00 66 A6 E6 4B E1 C8 68 20 21 38
AE FD 4C DF 40 39 08 32 82 29 B0 1D FE 17 ED 96
C3 66 6D 4A 12 1C E1 05 84 FF A8 85 C3 87 78 28
8D 43 10 F5 C7 BD 68 F6 11 08 68 DC FF 96 D8 C6
AC 7F 2F 1E 09 EF 80 33 ED 1D 91 CE D7 D8 92 41
58 9D 4F AA C4 9E 28 DD 53 BE E6 69 EC 08 86 3F
41 CB B5 48 1A 60 07 26 0B D5 1D E0 2F A4 B1 2E
23 EC 78 D8 F9 0C E9 FC 61 BD D8 B3 B4 09 CF 9A
```

Output

```
409CF9A
```

What I wanted to see was the whole data as a string stored in buf.

Comment: If you are opening file in binary then why not use `fread` ?

Comment: I think `getc()` would be the canonical way to obtain one char at a time from a file :-).

Comment: Actually originally it  was fscanf( f, "%02X", &c) , it was taking 2 characters and was putting those two in a buffer to make a string. I didn't saw that working properly so I changed it in this way.

Comment: `if (isPrint(c)) { /* the character is printable */ } else { /* this character isn't considered printable */ }`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `i` overflows because more than 255 characters are neither newline nor space. (If `i` is 255, `i++` will yield 0 on machines where a char has 8 bits.)

The string "ends" then at the first 0 character after that (or at end of file, whichever comes first) because you do not filter 0 characters out the way you skip newline and space when you copy characters to `buf`. (It "ends" there as far as printf's `%s` conversion is concerned, even though many characters may have been written past that position in the buffer.)

Make `i` an int or `size_t`, do not copy characters which are '\0' (actually: Follow Klas' advice from a comment to your post and use the portable and exhaustive `isprint()`, plus `isspace()`, if you are so inclined). Check for `buf`'s bounds. Simply use `getc()` for char-by-char reads, not `printf`.

As far as the output is concerned: `printf("%s", ...)` is not the appropriate way to display  "binary" data (i.e. byte values which include the values < 32, and probably values >127) because these byte sequences will be interpreted by your terminal (form feeds, backspaces overwriting earlier output, escape sequences changing the terminal settings, etc.). Either you filter those out, or you simply display hex data, the same way you showed us the original data.

Comment: I mended the program. In the output I still see newline characters.

Comment: That could be carriage return (13, `\r`). Just use something like `printf("%02x ", (int)buf[i])` for printing hex numbers. I hope I got the format right for printing a leading zero for small values...

Comment: What is the difference in newline and carriage return?

Comment: A carriage return should position the cursor at the beginning of a line, but not advance it. Terminals were modeled after teletypewriters, and those after typewriters. Advancing a line and returning to the beginning of a line were distinct operations.  Because they often occur together they were elegantly combined through the chrome lever to the right (you may remember the Jerry Lewis typewriter sketch). When Unix was conceived on a [9kB machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-7) Thompson e.a. decided that one could save valuable memory by omitting the `\r` before `\n`.

Comment: That is probably the second most severe Unix design error, right after [naming the file create function `creat()`,](https://books.google.de/books?id=poFQAAAAMAAJ&q=%22spell+creat+with+an+e%22&dq=%22spell+creat+with+an+e%22) and probably for similar reasons ;-).

Answer (score 1):

1. Here:

   ```
   unsigned char buf[512], i=0;
   ```

   `i` should be an integer.
2. Do not copy `'\0'` characters, otherwise printing string will always end up on first `'\0'` found.

Comment: As for point 2, the OP doesn't copy `\0`. He does it only after the loop as it is required.

Comment: @CoolGuy I thought he did, and the short output seems to support that (unless it's just EOF, but the chances are 1/20 or so). I think `%c` reads a 0 *sans probleme*, and it's not explicitly skipped either. (And the last `'\0'` is not a copy , btw.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Isn't the short output because of the overflow of `i`?

Comment: @CoolGuy We can't know (because I couldn't find the output in the data, so some of the data is not revealed to us, unless I am missing it). But that EOF happens within the first 8 bytes of a 512 byte buffer is fairly unlikely, assuming an even probability for some range of data lengths.